# No module named 'awsglue' for pytest runnig in local

Tags: amazon-web-services, pycharm, pytest, aws-glue

I am running pytest for aws glue job locally through pycharm.command pytest  throws following error. my source code seems to recognize awsglue, not sure why pytest throws this error. any leads is appreciated.

```
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
```

E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'awsglue'

Answer (score 0):

Three things I can think of:

1 - make sure you run from the right directory to recognize your files, in some cases, you'll need to configure a specific folder as source root:
[image]

2 - make sure you have __init__.py under you package

3 - make sure the intrepreter you are using to run the code is the same one you have your packages installed on